# How to use datatool package to read a CSV files so that they can be used in tables?

Tags: datatool

I am new in latex and I have some issues.
I want to read a .csv file in latex to create a table, but I don't know how.
I heard that **datatool** package can do this, but I don't know how to use it.

My input is smth like this:

```
,w5,w6,w7,w8,w9,w10,w11,w12,w13,w14,w15,w16,w17,w18,w19,w20,w21,w22,w23,w24
,25,23,13,14,15,39,36,4,37,11,26,13,34,39,40,22,33,32,9,5
,56,31,45,31,38,41,59,26,,44,52,33,,42,,28,51,41,28,36
```

Thank you!

**Update:**

I think I found the answer of how to create a table based on a csv file.
The name of the packages is actually [csvtools](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/csvtools).

Comment: `csvtools` is the old version of the package.  The current version is indeed called `datatool`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming that the first row is the name of the columns, then you simply need to load the database via `\DTLloaddb{myDB}{MyData.csv}` where the file `MyData.csv` contains the contents as shown above, and the you can use the internal function `\DTLdisplaydb{myDB}` to print it as a table.

This table is very wide so I used the `geometry` package to extend the width of the paper. Here is the first few columns of the table:

[image]

If the first row is not the header row, then you can specify the key for each column as:

```
\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={,ColW5, ColW6, ColW7}]{myDB}{MyData.csv}
```

where only keys for the first three columns have been included.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe,paperwidth=32cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{document}
    \DTLloaddb{myDB}{MyData.csv}
    \noindent\DTLdisplaydb{myDB}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And if I don't want to take in consideration the first row? Because it has to be like `w5 -> 5 to 6am`.