# How to convert a one digit number to a two digit number

Tags: numbering, conversion, strings

I have a table that represents a timetable for bus, so each cell contains time of departure as hour followed by minute, both as two digits, but sometimes I don't have two digits,just one so I have to switch eg. from `12 4 -> 12 04.`
How is it possible?

Comment: If you add a small usage example which shows the exact use-case people will be able to help you better. How do you get/import the data?

Comment: *Very* related is [How to output a counter with leading zeros?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30930/5764)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can define a macro as follows:

```
\newcommand\twodigits[1]{%
   \ifnum#1<10 0#1\else #1\fi
}

\twodigits{12}  % 12
\twodigits{4}   % 04
\twodigits{123} % 123
```

This macro is fully expandable.

If you also want to cut trailing zeros you can use:

```
\newcommand\twodigits[1]{%
   \ifnum#1<10 0\number#1 \else #1\fi
}

\twodigits{004} % 04
```

---

If you want to change a `tabular` cell from `12 4` to `12 04` without adding explicit macros you can use the `collcell` package to collect the cell content and feed it to a macro which splits the numbers by the space:

```
% preamble:
\newcommand\formatdate[1]{\formatdatei#1\relax}
\def\formatdatei#1 #2\relax{%
   \twodigits{#1} \twodigits{#2}%
}

\usepackage{collcell}

% later
\begin{tabular}{l>{\collectcell\formatdate}l<{\endcollectcell}}
   Bus date  & 12 4 \\
\end{tabular}
```

If you post a real usage example I can help me with more specific macros.

Comment: Thank you for response. Can you please take a look [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56160/how-can-i-use-dtlloaddb-package-to-create-a-table-based-on-csv-file)? I've added the question before with a case usage, but someone suggested to post a different question regarding this problem.

Comment: @IonMorozan: In such cases always add a link to the other question in the new question.

Comment: Yes you are right! It's is my third post on a forum, so I have to learn. Thank you for the feedback and by the way your solution works great for me. Thank you again!

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Thanks for pointing this out. I wrote the answer under my Windows installation were I don't have LaTeX installed, so I couldn't test it right away. I added a version which handles this kind of input without an assignment.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I found the following definition in latex.ltx ;-) `\def\two@digits#1{\ifnum#1<10 0\fi\number#1}`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Yes I vaguely remembered that something like this exists. However, here it is ok to define an own version. You avoid the need for `\makeatletter` etc. and the OP learns about `\ifnum`.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Indeed. I looked into the file to find another definition ;-)

Answer (score 22):

You can do that using the `siunitx` package

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\num[minimum-integer-digits = 4]{123}
\num[minimum-integer-digits = 4]{4}
\end{document}
```

prints

```
0123 0004
```

or alternatively you can declare the option as default,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\sisetup{minimum-integer-digits = 4}
\num{12}
\num{34}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you set `minimum-integer-digits` separately, as a default?

Comment: @percusse thanks for the edit, wasn't in front of a computer all day long..

Answer (score 8):

You can also use [the `xstring` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xstring/) to add the leading zero for single digits:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand*{\TwoDigit}[1]{%
    \IfStrEqCase{#1}{%
        {1}{0}%
        {2}{0}%
        {3}{0}%
        {4}{0}%
        {5}{0}%
        {6}{0}%
        {7}{0}%
        {8}{0}%
        {9}{0}%
    }#1%
}%
\begin{document}
123 $\to$ \TwoDigit{123}

12 $\to$ \TwoDigit{12}

2 $\to$  \TwoDigit{2}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use LaTeX's internal `\two@digit` for formatting:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\twodigit}[1]{\two@digits{#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\twodigit{12} \par % 12
\twodigit{4} \par  % 04
\twodigit{123}     % 123

\end{document}
```