# Number chapters as 01, 02, ... , 10, 11, ... appendices A, B

Tags: chapters

Minimal example (the problem is obvious):

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{
    \vspace*{-5.0em}
    {\parindent \z@  \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \LARGE{0\thechapter}
    \par\vspace{0.25cm}
    \flushleft\MakeUppercase{#1}}
    \par\vspace{3.5em}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\setcounter{chapter}{9}
\chapter{Tenth Chapter}

\appendix
\chapter{Appendix A}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:** I forgot to mention something important. Only the displayed chapter numbers should have 0s in front of them, not definitions, theorems, etc. That is: Chapter 01, Definition 1.1., etc.

Comment: [How to output a counter with leading zeros?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30930)

Comment: Yes. But you should be able to turn it off.

Comment: You are already defining the chapter head by hand, use the solution provided by egreg in the link. For the appendix, define the chapterhead once more leaving out the fix (or the zeo above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust the printing of `\thechapter` within `\@makechapterhead` to insert a `0` only if the value of the `chapter` counter is less than 10:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}% <cmd>
  {\thechapter}% <search>
  {\expandafter\ifx\@chapapp\appendixname\else\ifnum\value{chapter}<10 0\fi\fi\thechapter}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}

\begin{thm}
  A first theorem
\end{thm}
\setcounter{chapter}{9}
\chapter{Tenth Chapter}

\appendix
\chapter{Appendix A}
\begin{thm}
  Another theorem
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

The nested condition in the "replacement clause" of `\patchcmd` first checks whether you're in the appendix or not. If you aren't, then it prepends the `\thechapter` counter with 0, similar to the kernel [`\two@digits`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56207/5764) macro.

Comment: +1; Your patch is basically the command  `\two@digits` defined in the LaTeX kernel, so you could just write `\two@digits{\thechapter}`.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for picking that up. I've corrected for this in the updated post.

Answer (score 8):

Easy with `\numprint`and its `\nplpadding` command:

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage{numprint, apptools}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{
    \vspace*{-5.0em}
    {\parindent \z@ \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \LARGE{\ifappendix\Alph{chapter}\else\nplpadding{2}\numprint{\arabic{chapter}}\fi}%
    \par\vspace{0.25cm}
    \flushleft\MakeUppercase{#1}}
    \par\vspace{3.5em}
    \renewcommand\thechapter{\ifappendix\Alph{chapter}\else\npnolpadding\arabic{chapter}\fi}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}

\begin{thm}
  A first theorem
\end{thm}
\setcounter{chapter}{9}
\chapter{Tenth Chapter}

\appendix
\chapter{Appendix A}
\begin{thm}
  Another theorem
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Actually there's something I forgot to mention (sorry). I only want the displayed chapter numbers to have 0s. The definitions, theorems, etc. will be labeled normally. Any way to fix that? I'll leave the answer accepted because it's not that big of a deal, but I would like to fix it if possible.

Comment: @RandyRanderson: please see my updated answer.

Comment: @Mico: with `\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]`, it is modified, so I had to change my code.

Comment: Shouldn't the chapter numbering style be reset explicitly to `\Alph` in the appendix? Without such a reset, one would seem to get "01" in the page header instead of "A".

Comment: It doesn't have to. It seems the `\appendix` switch does it.removed. It's fixed now.

Comment: Hmm, I get a "01" in the header row above "Appendix A" when I run your latest code.

Comment: @Mico: solved, with `\ifappendix` from `apptools`.

Comment: But now the theorem-numbering gremlin is back. (Sorry, I really don't mean to torture you!)

Comment: Anyway, I like that sort of challenges. However the theorem numbering is normal in my case. How did you do?

Comment: @Mico: Solved again – until next time…

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution for ConTeXt users to force double digit numbers for the chapters. With the use of the `\startsectionblockenvironment` command one could provide setups which are only applied for a certain `sectionblock` environment.

```
\startsectionblockenvironment[bodypart]
    \setuphead[chapter][deepnumbercommand=\twodigits]
\stopsectionblockenvironment

\starttext

\startsectionblock[bodypart]

\chapter{First chapter}

\stopsectionblock

\startsectionblock[appendix]

\chapter{Appendix A}

\stopsectionblock

\stoptext
```

To have the same layout for the heading with the number on a separate line one has to write its own rendering alternative for it.

```
\defineheadalternative
  [stacked]
  [alternative=vertical,
   renderingsetup=headalternative:stacked]

\startsetups[headalternative:stacked]
    \vbox {
        \headsetupspacing
        \begstrut
        \ifconditional\headshownumber
            \headnumbercontent
            \par
        \fi
        \headtextcontent
    }
\stopsetups
```

After this is done with can load this new rendering with the `alternative` key from `\setuphead`.

```
\setuphead
  [chapter]
  [alternative=stacked,
   textstyle=WORD]
```