# Help with US Date Format

Tags: isodate, datetime2

I have searched the `isodate` package and the `datetime2` package to answer my question. I would like my date to be mm/dd/yyyy. The closest I have gotten is to have the date as dd/mm/yyyy. Could someone help me out.

I tried:

```
\usepackage[american,useregional=numeric]{datetime2}
\dateinputformat{american}
```

Comment: I would like to do this using the \today

Comment: With your code, I get 1/21/2016

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the American english (`USenglish`) and `num`eric format options to [`isodate`](http://ctan.org/pkg/isodate). This yields the output format mm/dd/yyyy:

> 01/21/2016

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[USenglish,num]{isodate}
\begin{document}
\today
\end{document}
```

The same output under [`datetime2`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2) (without defining your own date style):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[datesep={/}]{datetime2}
\DTMsetdatestyle{mmddyyyy}
\begin{document}
\today
\end{document}
```

Without any packages, you can just manage the printing yourself using `\day`, `\month` (in [two-digit format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56207/5764)) and `\year` explicitly:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\today}{\two@digits{\number\month}/\two@digits{\number\day}/\number\year}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\today

\end{document}
```

---

For calculations (like a two-digit year) on the date you can use the following:

> 01/21/16

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\today}{%
  \two@digits{\number\month}/% MM
  \two@digits{\number\day}/% DD
  \calc{\number\year-100*trunc(\number\year/100,0)}}% YY
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\today

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can set both separators in one go with `datesep={/}` if you like.

Comment: The datetime2 suggestion above worked. The isodate solution still returned dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: @JoeCiras: Not sure why. I've added a no-package option as well.

Comment: @Werner Just an additional question - in the manage yourself solution, how do you just have a two digit year? mm-dd-yy. I tried added \two@digits before the year statement but it looks like that command makes a one digit number a two digit number and does not truncate the date down to just two digits. Sorry for asking so many questions on this subject. I am new to customizing LaTeX.

Comment: @JoeCiras: See my updated answer.