# Easy way to sectioning with a leading zero

Tags: sectioning, numbering

There is a easy way to modify only this command

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}.}
```

in order to have an arabic counter with just one leading zero instead the original arabic without leading zero?

Comment: you mean like this`\renewcommand\thesection{\ifnum\value{section}<10\relax0\fi\arabic{section}}`

Comment: @touhami Better a space between `10` and `0` than `\relax`, so as to preserve full expandability.

Comment: Yes but there is something that give me an error. I think is ''\value'' do you know why?  @touhami

Comment: can you please add a minimal example that produce the error? for me it works fine.

Comment: I need some package in order to use '' \value ''?  LaTeX don't find that command

Comment: @touhami I think that I found the problem your command not work with one of my essential package that put the accents 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

Comment: no way! try again with `\renewcommand\thesection{\ifnum\value{section}<10 0\fi\arabic{section}}` or type it your self, don't copy paste

Comment: @AndreaLeo: `\value` is a `LaTeX` command -- it must be defined!

Comment: Related: [How to convert a one digit number to a two digit number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56207/5764)

Comment: @touhami I just love you! without copy-paste it work! Thank you so much! Have a nice TeX! :)

Answer (score 1):

This small document adds a leading zero in front of the section number and uses `15` dummy `\blinddocument` commands in the loop to fill up.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{blindtext}
\makeatletter
\let\latex@@thesection\thesection
\newcommand{\padwithzero}{%
  0%
}%
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\ifnum\c@section<10\relax\padwithzero\fi\latex@@thesection}
\newcount\dummycntr
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\loop\unless\ifnum\dummycntr=15
\begingroup
\blinddocument
\endgroup
\advance\dummycntr by 1
\repeat
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time but in the comments come out a simplest way! =)

Comment: @AndreaLeo: My solution is effectively the same ;-)