# Two digits chapter numbering in tableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents

Scraping through the documentation I managed to make so that `\chapter` generates a trailing 0 before the chapter number if the chapter number is smaller than 10.

I would like to do the same for table of contents but I couldn't find any help online. Right now I just see

```
1 First Chapter              5
2 Second Chapter            23
...
10 Tenth Chapter           130
```

But I want this:

```
01 First Chapter             5
02 Second Chapter           23
...
10 Tenth Chapter           130
```

Does anybody have a clue?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably didn't change `\thechapter`, but instead fiddled around with `\@makechapterhead`, correct? `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\ifnum\value{chapter}<10 0\fi\arabic{chapter}}` should suffice.

Comment: Could you provide us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates the current behaviour? That way we can best suggest alternatives to achieve your desired output.

Comment: Related/duplicates: [How to convert a one digit number to a two digit number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56207/5764); [How to output a counter with leading zeros?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30930/5764)

Comment: Thank you @Werner! So tableofcontents refers to \thechapter while makechapterhead just modifies the appearence of the chapter title?

Comment: Pretty much. I'm just guessing that's what you did...

Comment: By modifying `\thechapter` one gets the leading zero also in every cross-reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change of `\thechapter` should be done within `\@chapter` not in the `\@makechapterhead` command, since in `\@chapter` the `\addcontentsline` is used.

I assumed the `book` class for this.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xpatch}


\newcount\loopcntr


\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{%
  \@chapter%
}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
  {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
}{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\ifnum\value{chapter} <10\relax 0\arabic{chapter}\else\arabic{chapter}\fi}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
  {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
  \endgroup
}{\typeout{Patch successful!}}{\typeout{Patch failed!}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\loop\ifnum\loopcntr <10\relax
\advance\loopcntr by 1
\chapter{Kapitel \the\loopcntr}

\repeat

\end{document}
```

[image]