# How to handover a formatted number in a \foreach loop in another command?

Tags: formatting, expansion, loops, foreach

I hope somebody of you is able to help me with the following problem.
I have read over the last hours many posts about expanding commands before the result is used again but I am still not able to achieve my goal.

My problem is that I have a custom command with 2 input arguments `\printConvTablesd{"FileName"}{"Number"}` which imports a table based on the inputs. Inside the command it looks similar to this `\input{dri1/dir2/FileName_someotherStuff_Number}`. `"Number"` is then also used in the label of the table so the labeling follows the inputs.

This commands works as expected if and only if I insert the hard coded values for the two input arguments.

My idea was to set up a loop in order to make the document cleaner and easier to change since I need to use the loops multiple times.

The optimal output would look similar to this:

```
\foreach \Name in {Name1,Name2,...}
{
    \foreach \n in {0.05,0.10,0.55}
    {
        def\d\num[round-mode=places,round-precision=2]{\n}
        \printConvTablesd{\Name}{\d}
    }
}
```

The `\num`-command is needed since I need a special formatting for importing the table-files.
This peace of code produces the following error *Missing \endcsname inserted...*.

If I modify the code just a little to look something like the following it works alright:

```
\foreach \Name in {Name1,Name2,...}
{
    \printConvTablesd{\Name}{0.05}
    \printConvTablesd{\Name}{0.10}
    ...
    \printConvTablesd{\Name}{0.50}
}
```

So I guess the problem occurs because the second argument is handed over as command sequence and not as the result of the `\num[...]{...}` command. 
I am also guessing that I need some form of code expanding before

I would really appreciate if anybody of you could help me with that problem. 
If any more information are needed please let me know.

Comment: please fix your examples so that people can run then and see the problem `def\d\num` looks very odd it will typeset the word `def` then try to apply the accent command `\d` to `\num`. But it would be easier to debug a complete file rather than fragments

Comment: also does your second example really "work alright" with `\name` and `\Name` again it is very hard to tell if that is simply a typo or if there is missing code.

Comment: Hi David, you are right. In the code listed is a type. both `\name` and `\Name` should match upper and lower cases. This means either you change `\name` to `\Name` or the other way around.

Regarding posting a MWE it is not so easy since my document has nested `\input{}` over several levels. 
But I will try to add a MWE asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be some rounding errors that could occur with `\foreach` when using the `...` notation. This is mentioned in the [`pgf` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) (see section **83 Repeating Things: The Foreach Statement**). However, there seems to be no need for that here, as the enumeration is fairly straight-forward:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\printConvTablesd}[2]{%
  \par
  1: #1; 2: #2
}

\begin{document}

\foreach \Name in {Name1,Name2,Name4,Name10}
{%
  \foreach \Num in {5,10,...,55}
  {%
    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56207/5764
    \printConvTablesd{\Name}{0.\ifnum\Num<10 0\fi\Num}%
  }%
}

\end{document}
```

Your need for a double-digit number is solved by adding a leading `0` if `\Num` is `5`. See [How to convert a one digit number to a two digit number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56207/5764).

Comment: Hi Werner,
now it works! Thank you. I just needed to change `\printConvTablesd{\Name}{0.\Num\ifnum\Num<10 0\fi}` to `\printConvTablesd{\Name}{0.\ifnum\Num<10 0\fi\Num}`. Otherwise it produces *0.50* if `\Num == 5` instead of *0.05*.

Comment: @ExtremOPS: Sorry, yes. I swapped it and added a reference.