# Code breaks when exchanging \def with \edef

Tags: formatting, numbering, cleveref

I am trying to make a command which creates automatically incrementing IDs for entries in some lists I have to manage. They have to follow a certain formatting (for example the first character has to be the first letter of the current chapter). The IDs should be compatible with `cleveref` also, so I can `\cref` the according label and a customized reference appears.

The following code compiles:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{arrayjob}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{cleveref}


% entry counter
\newcounter{globalcounter}
\setcounter{globalcounter}{0}

\newcounter{localcounter}
\setcounter{localcounter}{0}


% chaptername tracker
\xpretocmd{\@chapter}
{%
\setcounter{localcounter}{0}%
\def\currentchapter{#1}%
%
}{}{}

% chapter number generator
\newcommand{\chapnumber}
{%
    \StrLeft{\thesection}{1}\StrRight{\thesection}{1}
}

% entrycode
\newcommand{\entrycode}
{
    \StrLeft{\currentchapter}{1}\chapnumber\padzeroes[2]{\decimal{localcounter}}
}


\newcommand{\cmust}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{globalcounter}%
    \stepcounter{localcounter}%
    \label{#1}%
    \def\current{\entrycode}%
    \current
}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Testchapter}

\cmust{test}
\cmust{test2}

\end{document}
```

and returns

[image: Compiled Doc]

which is basically what I want. But I dont know how to make `cleveref` use my "special" numbering system when referencing, so I tried to use the `arrayjob` package, creating an Array with the `cleveref` counter as an Index and my numbering as the value. But unfortunately the whole code breaks, when I try to evaluate my expression before the arrays saves the value (`\expandarrayelementtrue`). The same happens when I change the `\def` in the definition of `\cmust` below for a `\edef` but I just can't see why. Does anyone know

- why `edef` or `expandarrayelementtrue` breaks the code?
- if there is another way to convince `cleveref` to choose my style of referencing?
- if there is an easier way to save the evaluated result of an expression rather than the evaluatable expression itself?

Thanks in advance,

Moraxno

Comment: To the best of my knowledge it is not possible to use `\edef` with `\padzeros`.

Comment: But why is this? Are there alternatives or workarounds?

Comment: For the `cleveref` part, what have you tried? The manual covers customisation of the format - both high level and lower level changes.

Comment: Depends on how you define "why". The reason why I think this is true is that it has been noted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56207/how-to-convert-a-one-digit-number-to-a-two-digit-number). I also think that if you solve this problem, you will have an analogous issue with `\StrLeft` and `\StrRight`. Anyway, I fully agree with @cfr that you should use the cleveref package to adjust things to your needs.

Comment: @cfr Well, I defined an array like \newarray TheList and added a line to `\cmust` like `\TheList(\value{globalcounter})={\entrycode}` and later I defined a `\crefformat{globalcounter}{#2 \TheList(#1) #3}` but unfortunately these references never worked correctly, because the elements of the array where evaluated way to late and all the variables had already changed.

Comment: @marmot Well it seems like you are right about that. I haven't found a formating style for cref which allows this much customization, how would this be done?

Comment: it is always wrong to use `\edef` with "unknown"  tokens  especially if you use unexpandable commands like those from `xstring`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How do you recognize an unexpandable command? Are there expandable commands which provide string manipulation like `xstring`s ?

Comment: I've certainly used `\cref` for formatted lettered environments, for example, where the letter is determined on-the-fly when starting the environment. You basically have something not dissimilar here in terms of the chapter letter, for example: it is a fixed point, as far as the sections are concerned. But I've rarely used `xstring`, if ever, and never used the array thing you're working with - just fiddled somewhat with `cleveref`. (Usually, I use `fancyref`.)

Comment: @cfr This sounds exactly like my problem. Could you go more into detail please? How exactly did you create the letter from the environment? I just don't know, how to get this done without some overcomplicated redefining of commands and list keeping...