# How can I resize the page that a wide table can fit?

Tags: header-footer, paper-size

I am trying to make this table to fit on my page with those sizes:  non-standard paper size: width 28 cm, height 20 cm.Margins be set exactly in order to have the area available for text 27.5 cm wide and 18 cm high.

My code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[papersize=29cm,total=28.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{csvtools}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{datatool}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  {\Large \normalfont Services from Willesden Junction Underground Station towards Elephant \& Castle Underground Station}  


  \CSVtolongtable{data.csv}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}{
  \hline\hline
  \multicolumn{20}{|l|}{Monday--Friday}\\
  \hline \hline
  \bfseries \begin{tabular}{c}5 to\\6am\end{tabular} &
  \bfseries \begin{tabular}{c}6 to\\7am\end{tabular} &
  \bfseries \begin{tabular}{c}7 to\\8am\end{tabular} &
  \bfseries \begin{tabular}{c}8 to\\9am\end{tabular} &
  \bfseries \begin{tabular}{c}9 to\\10am\end{tabular} &
  \bfseries \begin{tabular}{c}10 to\\11am\end{tabular} &
  \bfseries \begin{tabular}{c}11 to\\Midday\end{tabular} &
  \bfseries \begin{tabular}{c}Midday\\to 1pm\end{tabular} &
  \bfseries \begin{tabular}{c}1 to\\2pm\end{tabular} &
  \bfseries \begin{tabular}{c}2 to\\3pm\end{tabular} &
  \bfseries \begin{tabular}{c}3 to\\4pm\end{tabular} &
  \bfseries \begin{tabular}{c}4 to\\5pm\end{tabular} &
  \bfseries \begin{tabular}{c}5 to\\6pm\end{tabular} &
  \bfseries \begin{tabular}{c}6 to\\7pm\end{tabular} &
  \bfseries \begin{tabular}{c}7 to\\8pm\end{tabular} &
  \bfseries \begin{tabular}{c}8 to\\9pm\end{tabular} &
  \bfseries \begin{tabular}{c}9 to\\10pm\end{tabular} &
  \bfseries \begin{tabular}{c}11 to\\Midnight\end{tabular} &
  \bfseries \begin{tabular}{c}Midnight\\to 1am\end{tabular}

  \\ \hline}
{%

      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w5}}{}}{\insertbyname{w5}&}{{\bf 05} \insertbyname{w5} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w6}}{}}{\insertbyname{w6}&}{{\bf 06} \insertbyname{w6} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w7}}{}}{\insertbyname{w7}&}{{\bf 07} \insertbyname{w7} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w8}}{}}{\insertbyname{w8}&}{{\bf 08} \insertbyname{w8} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w9}}{}}{\insertbyname{w9}&}{{\bf 09} \insertbyname{w9} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w10}}{}}{\insertbyname{w10}&}{{\bf 10} \insertbyname{w10} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w11}}{}}{\insertbyname{w11}&}{{\bf 11} \insertbyname{w11} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w12}}{}}{\insertbyname{w12}&}{{\bf 12} \insertbyname{w12} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w13}}{}}{\insertbyname{w13}&}{{\bf 13} \insertbyname{w13} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w14}}{}}{\insertbyname{w14}&}{{\bf 14} \insertbyname{w14} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w15}}{}}{\insertbyname{w15}&}{{\bf 15} \insertbyname{w15} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w16}}{}}{\insertbyname{w16}&}{{\bf 16} \insertbyname{w16} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w17}}{}}{\insertbyname{w17}&}{{\bf 17} \insertbyname{w17} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w18}}{}}{\insertbyname{w18}&}{{\bf 18} \insertbyname{w18} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w19}}{}}{\insertbyname{w19}&}{{\bf 19} \insertbyname{w19} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w20}}{}}{\insertbyname{w20}&}{{\bf 20} \insertbyname{w20} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w21}}{}}{\insertbyname{w21}&}{{\bf 21} \insertbyname{w21} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w22}}{}}{\insertbyname{w22}&}{{\bf 22} \insertbyname{w22} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w23}}{}}{\insertbyname{w23}&}{{\bf 23} \insertbyname{w23} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w24}}{}}{\insertbyname{w24}}{{\bf 24} \insertbyname{w24} }

\\
}
{
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w5}}{}}{\insertbyname{w5}&}{{\bf 05} \insertbyname{w5} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w6}}{}}{\insertbyname{w6}&}{{\bf 06} \insertbyname{w6} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w7}}{}}{\insertbyname{w7}&}{{\bf 07} \insertbyname{w7} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w8}}{}}{\insertbyname{w8}&}{{\bf 08} \insertbyname{w8} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w9}}{}}{\insertbyname{w9}&}{{\bf 09} \insertbyname{w9} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w10}}{}}{\insertbyname{w10}&}{{\bf 10} \insertbyname{w10} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w11}}{}}{\insertbyname{w11}&}{{\bf 11} \insertbyname{w11} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w12}}{}}{\insertbyname{w12}&}{{\bf 12} \insertbyname{w12} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w13}}{}}{\insertbyname{w13}&}{{\bf 13} \insertbyname{w13} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w14}}{}}{\insertbyname{w14}&}{{\bf 14} \insertbyname{w14} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w15}}{}}{\insertbyname{w15}&}{{\bf 15} \insertbyname{w15} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w16}}{}}{\insertbyname{w16}&}{{\bf 16} \insertbyname{w16} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w17}}{}}{\insertbyname{w17}&}{{\bf 17} \insertbyname{w17} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w18}}{}}{\insertbyname{w18}&}{{\bf 18} \insertbyname{w18} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w19}}{}}{\insertbyname{w19}&}{{\bf 19} \insertbyname{w19} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w20}}{}}{\insertbyname{w20}&}{{\bf 20} \insertbyname{w20} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w21}}{}}{\insertbyname{w21}&}{{\bf 21} \insertbyname{w21} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w22}}{}}{\insertbyname{w22}&}{{\bf 22} \insertbyname{w22} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w23}}{}}{\insertbyname{w23}&}{{\bf 23} \insertbyname{w23} &}
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertbyname{w24}}{}}{\insertbyname{w24}}{{\bf 24} \insertbyname{w24} }
\\
}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The output is like this:
[image]

And it suppose to be like this:
[image]

How can I resize the page that the table will fit?
And also is this the right way to add the heading?(`Services from Willesden Junction Underground Station towards Elephant \& Castle Underground Station`)

I have to say that I am using csvtool package to read a .csv file to create based on it a timetable for a bus station.

Comment: You might want to set the `\tabcolsep` length to a lower value.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Thank you! It worked, but I have one more question: As you can see the reference output(the second image) has the departure hours smaller than heading of the table(eg. `05 25` is smaller than `5 to 6am`). How can I do that? And also can you give me a tip regarding the heading, because I think I'm not doing in the right way. Thank you.

Comment: Is simply using `\small` enough? There is also `\scriptsize`, `\footnotesize` and `\tiny`. Ore make the header larger using `\large`.

Comment: Related Question: [How can I use \DTLloaddb package to create a table based on csv file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56160/how-can-i-use-dtlloaddb-package-to-create-a-table-based-on-csv-file)

Comment: @MartinScharrer Can you convert your comments to an answer?

Comment: @egreg: Now Done.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to set the `\tabcolsep` length to a lower value. This reduces the white space between the cell content and border and should result in the requested table size.